# Spring internationalization - manage and sync multiple files

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have been working on Spring projects that support multiple languages, using multiple key-value messages_[lang].properties files. They are relatively big applications, and the message files often have 1000+ lines. I usually develop for 2-3 different languages and it's a pain in the a** to add each message manually on each file. Supporting a big number of languages would be even more painful. Is there a good/simple/standard solution for this problem - managing and synchronizing message files in multiple languages?